# How do I use a dynamic variable as a Meteor/MongoDB collection name?

Tags: mongodb, variables, collections, meteor

So I tried this but it didn't work (on isServer) :

```
var tableName= "";
(...)
if (silly_cond === 1){
    tableName = "Table1";
}else{
    tableName = "Table2";
}
TableCol = new Mongo.Collection(tableName);
```

For some reason I can't get it to work. It seems to only accept

```
TableCol = new Mongo.Collection("Table1");
```

The idea was to fetch the tablename from the table ID, and apply the same JS to different tables (on different templates). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [dburles:mongo-collection-instances package](https://github.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances/). It let's me access any collection by the collection name. So in my example:

```
TableCol = new Mongo.Collection("Table1");
```

Using the above package I just write for example:

```
var dbvar = "Table1";
Meteor.Collection.get(dbvar).find()
```

and this way I can use variables to get collections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `tableName` outside the functions, otherwise it can't be seen.

```
var tableName = "";
if (silly_cond === 1){
    tableName = "Table1";
}else{
    tableName = "Table2";
}
TableCol = new Mongo.Collection(tableName);
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I also tried declaring the var without the "var" (in Meteor that creates a global var). Still a no go =/

Comment: I don't get an error, I just can't access the collection in the client. It works perfectly, until I try to change the collection name (on the isServer) by a variable, even if I declare the variable on the root dir .js file.

Comment: You say above that your code is in isServer - so it can't be accessed by client code

Comment: Forget last comment. I see what you're trying to do, no idea if it's possible or what the implications are. You're changing the publishing of a collection on the fly, right? Don't think I can help with that much. I'll see what I can find. It may be that your code is only being called once? You'll have to show all your code in more detail.

Comment: Found an awnser. I need to use Meteor.Collection instead of Mongo.Collection

I have no idea what's the difference but it works now. I'll research further

Comment: Meteor.Collection was renamed Mongo.Collection in 0.9.1. Sounds like you have an old version of Meteor. Anyway, glad it's working.

Comment: It's buggy. To be honest I don't understand why it's working only sometimes (seems like caching issues are getting in the way). I'll ignore it for now and do it by hand, and if I end up needing it later down the road, I'll get back to it.